# Is there any way to integrate google maps with google places and display it as part of my app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I was making a health based android app where when user presses a button, google maps get displayed on the screen along with locations of all hospitals within a kilometer radius marked.

I have used google places API to return JSON data of all hospitals within 1km but I don't know how to implement this.

Please do help me out.

Comment: I think 1km is a bit too less :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is put markers on the map to represent the location of each hospital. You do this like so:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title(placeName)
        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
```

Here, `mMap` is the Google Map and `placeName`, `lat and`lng` are the hospital details you've extracted from the JSON returned from the Places API.

More detail available in the [online docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker).